# Using Zend Gdata spreadsheets to get worksheet id

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, zend-gdata

I am trying to use zend gdata to get the worksheets for a spreadsheet. I am able to get the list of worksheets using

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
$feed = $spreadSheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
```

I was wondering how I could get worksheetId.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cycle through the worksheet ids like this:

```
foreach ($feed->entries as $entry)
{

/*use basename since this outputs a url & the id we need is just the last bit */

$worksheetId = basename($entry->id);

/* do something e.g.*/

echo $entry->title." : ".$worksheetId."\n";

}
```